Unable to get Fantomas Working correctly in F#
I can get Fantomas installed and working on Visual Studio 2022 . However, I cannot configure it.
I tried creating a .editorconfig file and putting the following in it
[*.{fs,fsx}]
fsharp_multiline_bracket_style = stroustrup

But this has no effect on the formatting when I press Ctrl + K , D
I have restarted a number of times.  My .editorconfig file is in the Solution root directory ( although I don't seem to be able to see it in the solution explorer which is odd )
